# Invalid TDE template

Tags: json, nosql, marklogic, tde

My MarkLogic database consists of a couple of sample documents in the folder "patents":

- /patents/airless_diving.json
- /patents/smart_racket.json
- /patents/tuning_ukulele.json
- /patents/waterski_drone.json

Each document looks like that:

```
{
  "patent": {
    "title": "Airless SCUBA diving", 
    "inventor": "Greg", 
    "description": "Diving pill that provides airless SCUBA diving for up to 1 hour"
  }
}
```

I am trying to create a template:

```
    const tde = require ('/MarkLogic/tde');
    
    const inventionsTemplate = xdmp.toJSON(
    {
      'template':{
        'context':'patent',
        'directories':["patents", "another_patents"],
        'rows':[
        {
          'viewName':'inventions',
          'columns':[
          {
            'name':'title',
            'scalarType':'string',
            'val':'../title',
            'nullable':true
          },
          {
            'name':'inventor',
            'scalarType':'string',
            'val':'../inventor',
            'nullable':true
          },
          {
            'name':'description',
            'scalarType':'string',
            'val':'../description',
            'nullable':true
          }
          ]
        }]
      }
    }
    );

tde.templateInsert('/templates/inventionsTemplate.json', inventionsTemplate);
```

But getting an error:

**[javascript] TDE-INVALIDTEMPLATE: (err:FOER0000) tde.templateInsert('/templates/inventionsTemplate.json', inventionsTemplate); -- Invalid TDE template: TDE-INVALIDTEMPLATENODE: Invalid extraction template node: fn:doc("")/template/array-node("rows")/object-node()**

Stack Trace
At line 75 column 6:
In tde.templateInsert('/templates/inventionsTemplate.json', inventionsTemplate);

fn:QName("http://marklogic.com/xdmp/tde","templateURI") = "/templates/inventionsTemplate.json"
fn:QName("http://marklogic.com/xdmp/tde","template") = document{object-node{"template":object-node{"context":text{"patent"}, "directories":array-node{...}, ...}}}
fn:QName("http://marklogic.com/xdmp/tde","permissions") = ()
fn:QName("http://marklogic.com/xdmp/tde","collections") = ()
fn:QName("http://marklogic.com/xdmp/tde","testvalid") = map:map(<map:map xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" .../>)
fn:QName("http://marklogic.com/xdmp/tde","permarray") = json:array()
fn:QName("http://marklogic.com/xdmp/tde","colsarray") = json:array()

What is the proper syntax for creating MarkLogic template driven extraction in my case?
Am I missing some preparation step before inserting TDE?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your [row](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/sql/creating-template-views#id_39718) is missing a `schemaName` property.

If you add that to the object in the `rows` array it will validate and insert.

```
'rows':[
    {
      'schemaName':'patents',
      'viewName':'inventions',
      'columns':[
```

The documentation could probably be improved to indicate which properties, such as `schemaName` and `viewName` are required and which are optional, such as `view-layout`.

Comment: Mads, thank you! It helped. Want to share with you also that it was not obviously for me what exactly to specify in "schemaName" property. Now I am realizing that I can just give some name and then my templates get stored in the configured schema database of my content database.  Initially I was thinking that some schema should be created in order to be used in that field.